# Is "Everyone tends to get the best of my worst" a valid sentence?

Tags: meaning, idioms, sentence

Is there any alternatives to the above sentence? I just needed to know how to say : "everyone tends to find my worst qualities easily" in a subtle way. And i really had no what to tag it with :)

Comment: “Everyone tends to get the best of my worst” is pluterperfect but only if you a writing a story.  I already want to know more about the character!

Comment: @ThirdNews what is wrong with it in a real scenario?

Comment: It has a distracting flow for straightforward communication. It has a poetic pull, and I googled your sentence because I thought it was pinched from a novel.  I am still unclear as to the purpose of your writing -is it matter-of-fact communication?

Comment: Well, it's not from a novel. I'm not much of a book reader. It's just that someone treated me in a way that i had to resolve to my worst attitude. And it got me thinking why do people tend to find those hidden characteristics of mine which i never want to expose. That's when this phrase popped up :) Hope it clears things up.

Comment: Why do you think it may not be a "valid sentence"? What exactly do you suspect? Grammar? Meaning?

Comment: That sentence is perfectly valid, but **it does not** express what you are trying to say.  the simple way to express, in English, what you are trying to say is very common: **Everyone sees the worst in me**.  it's that simple.

Answer (score 1):

**[Get my goat](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-does-gets-my-goat-mean.htm)** is an idiom that aptly describes your *Some people bring out the worse in me* sentiment.
If you use the idiom, you will be clearly understood.

**Get my goat**:

> When people say that something "really gets my goat,” they mean that
>   they are extremely irritated. A wide variety of things could
>   contribute to irritation, ranging from someone else's actions to a
>   series of events

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a very interesting sentence. It surely implies what you intend it to imply.
It is a valid sentence.

Answer (score -1):

*Everyone tends to zero in on my negative qualities without thinking twice.*

Comment: Everyone sees the worst in me, everyone picks up on the worst in me, people only see my bad side, everyone only notices my bad side.